# How to pad multiple strings when writing to console so that part is aligned left and part is aligned right?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write lines one at a time to the console and to an output file. I am not able to figure out how to pad the string so that the left part of the string is aligned left and the right part is aligned right similarly between different WriteLines's and StreamWrite's.

I've tried using the \t which works nicely if the left part of the string is similar in length to other strings, but fails if the strings are too different in length.

```
{
sw.WriteLine($"{now} {typeOfTransaction} \t ${transacAmnt:0.00} ${currentbalance:0.00}");
}


Expected Output:
6/10/2019 4:15:44 PM Added Money         $10.00 $10.00
6/10/2019 4:15:53 PM Cloud Popcorn A4    $10.00 $6.35
6/10/2019 4:15:55 PM Cash Out            $6.35 $0.00

Actual Output:
6/10/2019 4:15:44 PM Added Money         $10.00 $10.00
6/10/2019 4:15:53 PM Cloud Popcorn A4    $10.00 $6.35
6/10/2019 4:15:55 PM Cash Out    $6.35 $0.00
```

Comment: @itsme86 The proposed duplicate only explains how to pad strings. This question is about left/right aligning text in columns. There is more to answering this question than just padding the strings. Do the columns have to be fixed-width, or should they grow based on the largest item in that column?

Comment: @Romen If you stick 2 left-/right-padded string strings together, you get columns. I didn't think it was too much of a leap.

Comment: @itsme86, I left a question at the end of that comment that I hoped Brad L would see too. If they needed variable sized columns then `string.Format()` isn't enough. An answer providing fixed width columns was selected already so I guess that's all they needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `String.Format + {index,length}`

#### e.g:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}  {1,-20}  ${2,-10} ${3,-10}", DateTime.Now, "Added Money", 10.00,10.00));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}  {1,-20}  ${2,-10} ${3,-10}", DateTime.Now, "Cloud Popcorn A4", 10.00,6.35));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}  {1,-20}  ${2,-10} ${3,-10}", DateTime.Now, "Cash Out", 6.35,0.00));
```